# Check if cookie exists - Chrome Extensions

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cookies

Heyho,
I got a function to get cookies and it works fine (except the if-part in getCookies()):

```
function getCookies(domain, name, callback) {
chrome.cookies.get({"url": domain, "name": name}, function(cookie) {
    if(callback) {
        callback(cookie.value);
    } 
});
}

//USER ID
getCookies("http://free-way.me", "uid", function(id) {

    if(id == null) { document.getElementById("submulti").disabled = true;}
    else { document.getElementById("user").value = id;}
});
```

Well, when there's no cookie the console gives me this:

```
Error in response to cookies.get: TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null
at getCookies [...]
```

No surprise, but I don't know how to check if the the request worked, and return the error to disable the submit-button.

It would be nice if you could help me..

Thank you,
Markus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just throw in a quick extra check on the value of `cookie` before attempting to access the `value` attribute?

```
chrome.cookies.get({'url': domain, 'name': name}, function(cookie) {
    if (callback) {
        callback(cookie ? cookie.value : null);
    }
});
```

The ternary check there will make sure you return `null` when `cookie` is `null`. Let me know if that wasn't your question!

Comment: Thank you, I will try it on friday, but it looks good. Thank you so far